# How to get all data from database when parameter is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to show some data coming from a database in a page (VIEW) using the WHERE clause as a variable. but failed to get the expected data.

```
$this->db->select('vehicle.*,vec_source.vec_Source,vec_images.image1');
    $this->db->from('vehicle');
    $this->db->join('vec_images', 'vehicle.vec_Id = vec_images.vec_Id_fk','inner');
    $this->db->join('vec_source', 'vehicle.vec_Id = vec_source.vec_Id_fk','inner');
    $this->db->where_in('Make',$make);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

The above query is working fine but when the variable **$make** is empty, then how to show full results as **Where Like ='%'** how to achieve this in **IN Clause**

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

Just add `where_in` using `if`:

```
// previous code here
$this->db->join('vec_source', 'vehicle.vec_Id = vec_source.vec_Id_fk','inner');
if (!empty($make)) {
    $this->db->where_in('Make',$make);
}
$query = $this->db->get();
// more code here
```

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder but tell me how to get full result from database as **like clause**  do `LIKE ('%') ` but how to achieve this with **IN CLAUSE** ??

Comment: I don't understand, what is the expected query with `IN`?